# Faulty Voltage regulator?

Tags: surface-mount

Cant identify what is this ...SMD
The only thing i can understand is that is Motorola.[image]
Any help appreciated.

Comment: What makes you think this part is at fault?

Comment: U see the krack ?

Comment: Ah yes. Unexpected failure or over stressed ?

Comment: It may be over stressed...i suppose :)

Answer (score 3):

It is almost certainly a 24V Unidirectional TVS, made by Motorola (now ON Semiconductor).
The datasheet for On-Semi's [1.5SMC24AT3](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/ON%20Semiconductor%20PDFs/1.5SMC%20SERIES.pdf) device lists "24A" as the device marking and the SMD device package (SMC/Case-403) matches.

Comment: The device is from automotive module (Motorola phone module) and its burning the 12v 5amp fuse , i would say that its should be 12v device...

Comment: A TVS used in an automotive circuit can't be a 12V device. It would die in short order since automotive voltage levels routinely exceed 12V.

Comment: Im confused ....so can this be 24V Unidirectional TVS ?

Comment: Yes - it can be, and from the (limited) evidence I think it probably is. I'd guess that its purpose would be to protect the circuit from excessively  overvoltage (more than 24V on a 12V rated device is not normal, even for automotive) and possibly protect from reverse polarity too (since it's a *unidirectional* TVS). Does your device power up now with this part removed and not blow the fuse?

Comment: Yes the fuse is ok and the module powers up with the device removed.

Answer (score 0):

It may just be the light, but I think there is a lighter patch on the side which is damaged. This would suggest to me that this is some sort of diode.

It looks to me like it reads 2.4A.

Comment: I can post more photos tomorrow morning. As i answered to brhans , this is from 12v 5amp module (burning fuse)